# Spring property name casing by example

Tags: java, spring

Spring will automatically bind properties defined in `application.properties` or `application.yml` to fields defined in `@ConfigurationProperties`-annotated classes. For instance, in my `application.properties` I can have:

```
fizz.buzz=35
fizz.foo=hello
```

And in my Java code I can have:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("fizz")
public class FizzProperties {
    private Integer buzz;
    private String foo;
    // ...
}
```

And at runtime `FizzProperties#buzz` will get a value of `35` injected into it and `FizzProperties#foo` will have a value of `"hello"` injected into it.

I'm wondering what the naming convention is for camel-cased Java fields, and also for hyphens (`"-"`) and periods (`"."`) used in the properties files. For instance, if I had:

```
fizz.whistle-feather=true
fizz.baz.boo=always
```

What would their corresponding Java fields need to look like in order for Spring to map and inject them properly?

```
public class Baz {
    private String boo;
}

@ConfigurationProperties("fizz")
public class FizzProperties {
    private Integer whistleFeather; // correct?
    private Baz baz; // correct?
    // ...
}
```

**Are my assumptions correct here or misled (and if misled, how so)?** I can't find this explained in the Spring docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in spring-boot docs, it uses ["relaxed binding"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding), so both properties *"whistle-feather"* and *"whistleFeather"* will be mapped to your `private Integer whistleFeather`, but it's recommended, when possible, to store properties in lower-case kebab format, such as `fizz.whistle-feather=10`.

So your first case is correct.

The second case is also correct, because dots are used as delimiters in `application.properties`, while YAML file uses as delimiters both dots and colon.

You also may define nested properties as nested classes to store them in one place like this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("fizz")
public class FizzProperties {
    private Integer whistleFeather;
    private Baz baz;
    // getters, setters
    
    public static class Baz {
        private String boo;
        // getters, setters
    }
}
```

Take a look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties) for more info about spring-boot properties binding and examples.